# One time memory allocation or dynamic allocation

Tags: memory, memory-management

I have a program that needs between 2k to 4M memory for each thread. The threads are continuously spawned(say 20 threads), so once it comes into being it needs memory between 2k - 4m (randomly), uses it, exits and is spawned again. 
Now I want to know should I allocate maximum that is 4M memory once for each thread and use that memory even when i need lesser memory, that avoids allocating and freeing mem every time and can prevent fragmentation. But the downside is I see lot of page faults happening when thread count increases to 100  or more.

Not sure how to decide the implementation. Any suggestions are helpful?

Comment: We have memory pool concept too. Try to implement or use exisiting memory pool library.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool

Answer (score 0):

Normally (notable exception to this description: Mobile device), there is one heap for all threads that resides in the process. If a thread allocates memory, that gets added to the process address space. If the thread dies and a new one comes along, it can reallocate memory used by the previous thread.

You may want to use operating system services or library functions to preallocates a heap of suitable size so that you are not continuously expanding the heap.